# How do I test if a PHP variable is part of a specific array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Basically I have this:

```
<?php
    $variable = 8;
    if ( $variable == array(5,6,7) ) :
    echo '<p>'.$variable.'</p>;
    endif;
?>
```

Can I test if a variable is one of those values like that or do I have to test each individually, like:

```
<?php
    $variable = 8;
    if ( ( $variable == 5 ) || ( $variable == 6 ) ) :
    echo '<p>'.$variable.'</p>;
    endif;
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`in_array()`](http://us.php.net/in_array):

```
if(in_array($variable, array(5,6,7) )){
    // $variable is in the array!
}
```

Comment: @BiffWebsterJr. You're welcome - glad it worked for you. Please be sure to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you get the chance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
if (in_array($variable, array(5,6,7))) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array($variable, array(5, 6, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function for this